# var keyword with Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#

There's been some question where I work about use of the var keyword when casting the result of Activator.CreateInstance to an interface type. As I understand var, the following snippet pairs are pretty much identical between the var version and the explicit type version:

```
// Direct cast
var thing = (IThing)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(thingType));
IThing thing = (IThing)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(thingType));

// Casting with as
var thing = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(thingType)) as IThing;
IThing thing = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(thingType)) as IThing;
```

Are there any subtle differences I'm missing that might change Intellisense or runtime behavior?

Comment: Your final sentence implies you are seeing some differences - can you be more specific? (or am I reading too much into it?)

Comment: *I* see no difference, but I was debating the merits of var with a coworker and this came up. We both weren't sure, and I'd rather be sure than sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. The '`var`' keyword doesn't do anything magical, it uses compile time type inference, similar to how generics work.

Once it's compiled, there is no difference. You can prove this with your IDE by hovering over the variable name where it is being used (other than where it is declared). A tooltip should pop up showing you the type. Both variables should have the same type when hovered over.

Comment: Comparing the IL will be even more proof should anyone remain unconvinced.

Comment: IL would be a better proof, but if you don't want to go into the IL, then the IDE is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In each case declaring thing as `var` or `IThing` is synonymous.

There are differences between the cast and using `as` - the latter will return `null` if the item isn't what you're trying to convert to.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no difference. Also I don't see any problem in using the `var` keyword.

In terms of readability, looking at the following lines of code you easily see witch `Type` the `var` is:

```
var thing = (IThing)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(thingType));
var thing = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(thingType)) as IThing;
```

Comment: Agreed. That's what the whole debate was about. I thought var was easier to read, my coworker thought it was harder. But I think with the second line, an explicit type is warranted because the type being cast to is so far to the right that it takes some searching.

Answer (score 0):

var and IThing are identical.  You just save 3 keystrokes.